# jQuery DataTable updates the first rows of the table not the selected ones

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I have a Laravel App where i'm using jQuery DataTables to update some records. I retrieve those records from the database and i have to confirm them. On the DataTable i have a checkbox at the last column.

[image: The DataTable]

Now I can update records from the database when I select the checkbox, but the updated record does not correspond to the record on the checkbox row. Here is before update:

[image: Selected Row in the DataTable]

And here is after the records are updated:

[image]

As you can see it's the record with month = 3 updated instead of the record with month = 4.

Here is the code on the controller:

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $is_validated = $request->get('is_validated');
    $rec_id = $request->get('id');
    $reports = [];
    foreach($is_validated as $key => $valid){
        $id = $rec_id[$key];
        if(!empty($valid)){
            $reports[] = DB::table('reports')->where('reports.id', $id)->update(['is_validated' => 1, 'validated_by' => $user->id]);
        }else{
            $reports[] = DB::table('reports')->where('reports.id', $id)->update(['is_validated' => 0, 'validated_by' => $user->id]);
        }
    }
}
```

All the help or hints are appreciated.

**EDIT**

I tried reordering the columns and the very first columns on the datatable were updated, no matter what their id was.

**EDIT 2**

This is the javascript where the request parameters are set.

```
columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'reports.id'},
            {data: 'month', name: 'reports.month'},
            {data: 'value', name: 'reports.value'},
            {data: 'comment', name: 'reports.comment'},
            {data: 'is_validated', name: 'reports.is_validated'},
        ],
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets": [0],

            "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                return '<input type="text" name="id[]" data-name"id-' + meta.row + '" value="'+data+'" class="hidden"/>';
            }
        },{
            "targets": [4],

            "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
                return '<input name="is_validated[]" data-name"is_validated-' + meta.row + '" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" unchecked/>';
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Check, if `$is_validated` gives the correct selected ID or not. Please mention whether it should execute if or else block?

Comment: `$is_validated` gives the checkbox input. however `$rec_id` does give the correct id. and yes it should execute if/else block

Comment: Please show your JavaScript code demonstrating how you set `id` and `is_validated` request parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code, but the main is that the browser sends `id[]` parameters for all text boxes but only those `is_validated[]` containing checked values, so length of both arrays is different and you calculate your ID incorrectly in your PHP.

Instead you need to have a value for each checkbox that will be equal to the record ID. On the server side you need to check whether both IDs are present in `id[]` and `is_validated[]`; if yes, then the check box is checked, otherwise it's unchecked.

Corrected code is shown below:

**JavaScript:**

```
columns: [
   {
      data: 'id', 
      name: 'reports.id',
      "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
         return '<input type="text" name="id[]" data-name="id-' + meta.row + '" value="'+data+'" class="hidden"/>';
      }
   },
   {data: 'month', name: 'reports.month'},
   {data: 'value', name: 'reports.value'},
   {data: 'comment', name: 'reports.comment'},
   {
      data: 'is_validated', 
      name: 'reports.is_validated',
      "render": function ( data, type, full, meta ) {
         return '<input name="is_validated[]" data-name="is_validated-' + meta.row + '" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="' + full['id'] + '"/>';
      }
   },
],
```

**PHP:**

```
public function update(Request $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $is_validated = $request->get('is_validated');
    $rec_id = $request->get('id');
    $reports = [];
    foreach($rec_id as $id){
        if(in_array($id, $is_validated)){
            $reports[] = DB::table('reports')->where('reports.id', $id)->update(['is_validated' => 1, 'validated_by' => $user->id]);
        } else {
            $reports[] = DB::table('reports')->where('reports.id', $id)->update(['is_validated' => 0, 'validated_by' => $user->id]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the actual code gives `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. I changed it a little bit at `value=' + full['reports']['id'] + '` and also at the controller method, but now it seems like the condition isn't met  in the if sentence even why i checked the box. after checking with chrome inspect element i saw that `is_validated` input has an undefined value.